# How to do grouping on multiple rows in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have `Column 1`, `Column 2`, `Column 3`, `Column 4`, `Column 5`, `Column 6`, in my Table. I have `Group`ed on `Column 1` and `Column 2`, but when I `Group` on Column 6, it does the grouping but sits between `Column 1` and `Column 2`.  I want to `Group` on `Column 6` and it should stay in the same place. (i.e `Column 6`). How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you post the code, that would help..

Comment: Hello Johny. The requirement has changed. Now instead of drag and drop the datasets into the Tablix, i need to create a Matrix. As i am new to SSRS, how can i use some as just fields, and some i need to do Row Groups. How can i achieve this using Matrix.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. Maybe some general tutorials would help: http://ssrstutorials.blogspot.com/2012/10/lesson-15-ssrs-matrix-reports.html              https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Insert a table on your report.

1. In the first column, select your Column 6 (C6) field.
2. In the Grouping window, set your RowGroup (probably defaulted the name to Details) Group Properties and Group On your C6 field.
3. On the table, right-click on the cell with your C6 group and Add Group->Row Group->Parent Group. Repeat step 2 for you C2 field.
4. Repeat step 3 for your C1 field.
5. Right click on the **column** with your C2 field and Insert Column->Inside Group-Right.
6. Repeat step 5 two more times for your C3, C4, and C5 fields.

For more on Grouping in SSRS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services